# Como converter números em python

Tags: python

Hoje, estou aqui para tirar a dúvida de algumas pessoas sobre como converter números em python
imaginemos que temos uma variável `num = 12` e quisessemos converter ela

```
# para converter em octal
print(oct(num))
```

a saída neste caso seria

```
0o14
```

detalhe importante: o "0o" na frente do número significa que ele está em octal

```
# para converter em hexadecimal
print(hex(num))
```

a saída neste caso seria

```
0xc
```

detalhe importante: o "0x" na frente do número significa que ele está em hexadecimal

```
# para converter em binário
print(bin(num))
```

a saída neste caso seria

```
0b1100
```

detalhe importante: o "0b" na frente do número significa que ele está em binário.
O problema do "0b", "0x", e "0o" pode ser resolvido usando

```
num_convertido = hex(num) # no exemplo usei hex, mas tamém poderia ser oct e bin
print(num_convertido[2:]) # se tiverem dúvidas sobre isso podem pesquisar sobre "slices"
```

este post é um tira-dúvida que fiz para ajudar outras pessoas

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)).

Comment: **Os comentários foram [movidos para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148419).** Para futuras publicações, antes de comentarem, revisem os [**objetivos dos comentários**](/help/privileges/comment).